# TFS 2015 off shore Build does not take files from proxy

Tags: tfs, proxy, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have some problems with our TFS 2015 Build in our off shore location.

We have our main TFS in Austria and an already working proxy (TFS 2013) in India. 
I have created a TFS 2015 Buildagent which is also working but it is not able to gather the files from the proxy.
I have configured the build machine like it is stated on this Microsoft site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716770(v=vs.120).aspx

But it still downloads all the files from our TFS which takes up to 15 Minutes with a good connection.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy was provided for older versions of TFS.  One of the great features of the new build system is you can place the agent wherever your files are.  Setup up the build agent where the files are instead of going through a proxy.  You will still need to connect the build agent to the server but that may work better.

Comment: But we have tons of Code and many branches therefore we need to cache them in India and we need a few buildagents.

Comment: I understand the need to cache the source in India.  I'm saying if your build agent is also in India then you don't have to traverse the proxy to build which may resolve your issue.  Your original post made it sound like your build agent was in Austria.